# Receiving files from Android via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, android, data-transfer

I currently have an Android application that is paired to my Pi via the Bluetooth dongle. In order to receive a file, I have to manually accept for the transfer to occur.

Is there way to bypass this step? Or to have all the transfers automatically accepted and stored in a specific directory?

Comment: How are you currently accepting the transfer? I use the blueman applet and with that I believe I can set a device as trusted to automatically receive files. It also has a setting for the destination directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to transfer files between your pi and android phone then the whole process is simple you can refer to this article http://thetechmaniacs.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/raspberry-pi-ftp-easiest-on-the-world-wide-web/ otherwise you probably have to hassle with the app because of bluetooth security standards.Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If you could include the important info from the link it would make your answer more useful and help keep this site/Q:A more useful in the future, as including this info protects against link rot.

Comment: I think you missed the "via bluetooth" part